# Android & Apache POI - не удается подключить библиотеку в gradle проект

Tags: android, android-studio, xls, apache-poi, android-gradle

Никакими способами не удается подключить к Android проекту библиотеку Apache POI для работы с xls Файлами. Как не варьировал с кодом по инфо с форумов, все также идут экзэпшн вроде этой:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory
```

причем ругается постоянно на строку `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();`
Пробывал по разному подключать библиотеку и доп библиотеки в gradle билде, и локально скачивая и ссылками. Результатов - ноль. Помогите, пожалуйста, у кого это подключение осуществилось, либо советом!

Comment: Может так пройдет. Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(); Дело в том, что в Android есть ограничение на 65К методов в приложении, а для работы XSSF необходим jar, содержащий Open XML Schemas, в котором даже в сокращенной версии для POI содержится около 67К методов.

Comment: Работает! Я думал оба формата не более 67к методов... Прописывал мультеиндексы:
multiDexEnabled true
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
Спасибо!